# Rotation in x64 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Below are my instructions. Kinda struggling and dont know what to do..

Your program should start by calling ReadString (IO.cpp) to get a message of some reasonable length.
Next, call a PROC to perform the encryption, saving the result in a new memory location.
Call DisplayMemory to show the encrypted values on the screen.  Also show (but encryption not necessary) the sentinel value returned by ReadString.  Call DisplayNewline.
Then, call a PROC to decrypt your encrypted message (by rotating all the bits in each byte 3 positions to the left).
Finally, call DisplayString to display your decrypted message.  It should match the user-entered string.

Here is some sample output (the first line is entered by the user):

```
now is the time for all good men
73 7b bb 01 4b 9b 01 a3 43 2b 01 a3 4b 6b 2b 01 33 7b 93 01 0b 63 63 01 3b 7b 7b 23 01 6b 2b 73 00
now is the time for all good men
```

And this is my code so far:

```
extrn ExitProcess:          PROTO
extrn DisplayString:        PROTO
extrn ReadString:           PROTO

.data?
string1         byte        40 dup(?)
string2         byte        ?

.code
Rotate          PROC

                mov  rax, 0                     ;counter = 0
Loop1:
                cmp  rax, rdx                   ;counter is less than string1 length
                jge  Done                       ;exit loop once string is processed
                mov  al, byte ptr[rcx + rax]
                ror  al, 3
                mov  byte ptr[rcx + rax], al

                inc rax
                jmp Loop1

Done:
                mov  byte ptr[r8 + rax], 0
                mov  rax, r8
                ret                                 ;return
Rotate          ENDP

main            PROC
                push rbp                            ;save non-volatile  
                mov  rbp, rsp                       ;make frame pointer for stack
                sub  rsp, 32                        ;reserve shadow space

                lea  rcx, string1
                call ReadString
                call Rotate
                sub  eax, 1
                mov  edx, eax
                lea  rcx, string2
                mov  rcx, rax
                call DisplayString

                add  rsp, 32                        ;restore shadows space
                pop  rbp                            ;save non-volatile stack
                xor  rcx, rcx                       ;return code
                call ExitProcess                    ;windows exit
main            ENDP
END
```

Comment: It's unclear why you rotate the address or why you even have multiple rotates. It's as simple as `rol byte ptr [rcx + rax], 3` while looping over the data.

Comment: I assumed the [tag:monetdb-assembly-language] was a mistake, so replaced with [tag:x86-64].

Comment: Please don't break the code-formatting when you make edits.

Comment: Note that `al` is the lowest 8 bits of `rax` and is not a completely different register; so when you use `al` for the character data you're corrupting `rax` used for indexing.